# SVN repository subfolders are checked out from different repos

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I had set a new svn repository and relocated all users to it.

But even after relocation some users had subfolders that had been checked out from different repo.
So is there any way check this and relocate all folders to the same repository.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the repository has externals enabled in it.

Do the following in the root of your working copy to list all the externals in your repository:

```
svn propget svn:externals -R
```

You may have to manually changes those links to the desired location with the following syntax

```
svn propset svn:externals PROPNAME PROPVAL PATH
```